# Font-Awesome doesnt work in NativeScript although i followed every step

Tags: nativescript, font-awesome

The Icons I included in Nativescript dont work.
I followed every Step in this tutorial but the Icons look like in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV5V4.png).

[image]

I tried using different versions of Font-Awesome.
The Desktop and the web-version. I know that the Web-Version is the right one but you never know.

I Included Font-Awesome like this.

```
.far {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', fa-regular-400;
    font-weight: 400; 
}

.fab {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands', fa-brands-400;
    font-weight: 400; 
}

.fas {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', fa-solid-900;
    font-weight: 900; 
}
```

And i used it like so:

```
<Label class="far" style="font-size: 50em; color: blue" text="&#xf130;"></Label>
```

Answer (score 2):

For custom fonts, you need to add the font file in a folder `src/fonts`.
Based on your picture, it's Android you are using, and on that platform, your CSS `font-family` must match the font file name, ie. `FontAwesome` if your font file is named `FontAwesome.ttf`.
On iOS the font family must match the name in the font file - check out https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-custom-fonts-in-a-nativescript-app
for more details.

Edit: Maybe you are just missing quotes around the font (file) names,

ie.

```
.far {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'fa-regular-400';
}

.fab {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands', 'fa-brands-400';
}

.fas {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'fa-solid-900';
}
```

I've created a Playground:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=yUV2G5

and the three icons are displayed correctly on iOS.

Comment: I included the tff file in the src/app folder. And the name of the font are "fa-regular-400","fa-brands-400" and "fa-solid-900". in the code snippet you can see that i included these in the font family.

Comment: Try moving it to src/fonts, and do a `tns platform clean android` before rebuilding.

Comment: It is in src/fonts my bad. tns platform clean android didn't help. Do you know what else i could try.

Comment: Maybe you are just missing quotes around the font (file) names. I've added a Playground - see edited answer.